# How to include additional information in library exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I am working on a library and I want to include additional contextual information in all the exceptions which are thrown from the library,
including in the exceptions which are not library specific, e.g. `System.NullReferenceException`. (Most probably, this additional information will help the developers to debug issues with their code and/or data.)
**EDIT**: My library is processing some big data structures which can also be very nested. So I want to include as additional information the full path of the field which is processed when the exception is thrown, e.g. `MyClass.Field1.SomeArray[10].SomeOtherField.ThisFails`. (I think that in this case will be a very useful piece of information to add in exceptions).

Solution 1. I know that wrapping is the recommended way to include additional contextual information in exceptions.
But I think it has a big downside: you have to change the type of the exceptions. 
So, for example an `OutOfMemoryException` will be wrapped in some library specific exception and it will be much more difficult for the application to handle this specific exception
(the developers will have to check the type of the `InnerException` property).
That's why I want to avoid wrapping the exceptions. (An additional consideration against wrapping is that my library will work with some objects implemented by the users, which may throw their specific  exceptions, and I do not want to modify the type of these exceptions.)

Solution 2. I decided to use the `Exception.Data` dictionary to include this additional information in the exceptions.
The downside of this solution is that the additional information will not be included in the result of the default implementation of `Exception.ToString()`.
(I would like to include additional information in the result of `Exception.ToString()`, so that it will be easily visible to the developers which log exceptions with something like
`log.Write(ex.ToString());`; in this way the dvelopers will not have learn how to invoke some other formatting method from my library.)

**EDIT**:
Solution 3. I thought of appending my information at the end of the `exception.Message` field using reflection (since this is readolnly). Are there any good reasons why I should avoid this?

Are there any other possible solutions to this problem which will avoid the explained downsides? If there are no other better solutions, which of the above is the most common implementation?

**EDIT**:
I want to make it clear, since this is a library, I do not have much control over what kind of exception logging the user will use and how much of the library's documentation they will read. I want to avoid meaningless support requests by including as much information as possible in the result of `ex.ToString()`.

Also, performance is important for this library (that might be just for marketing, but then it is even more important) so, for the **well behaved scenarios**, I will want to avoid any extra processing. That is, if possible, I also want to avoid some extra checks like `if (data.Field == null) throw new ArgumenNullException("someField");` since, if there is something wrong with the data, the code will just fail a little bit later with a `NullReferenceException`, which I can catch in a convenient location and use some method to add data in it.

Comment: I use a dependency injected exception handler, and exceptions from all classes get funnelled into it.  The handler classifies exceptions as forgivable, unforgivable, tolerated, etc and does all the logging.

Comment: @GayotFow can you give me some more details about the implementation (maybe as an answer to this question).

Comment: Are you using dependency injection?  I can have a go if that's your pattern

Comment: @GayotFow I do not use dependency injection (and since this is a library I am not sure that it will be ok to ask the user to handle extra dependencies). Anyway, if you have some time maybe it will worth to explain how you do it, maybe it will help (and it may be useful for other people).

Answer (score 2):

If you are open to adding a new method, such as `ToLogString()`, as an extension method on the type `Exception`, that could combine the default `ToString()` with stuff from `Exception.Data`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you define a set of broad case, and to some degree finer detailed exceptions that you know your library can throw. These would be exceptions that prohibit your library from living up to its defined expectations (within your control) even if the exception is thrown because of misuse on the users part.

For example, missing Null values - Since you can't always enforce users of your library to follow the rules you lay out throw what is natural. `throw new ArgumentNullException("Some message")` or throw `new MyLibraryArgumentNullException()`.

In certain cases you may want to introduce a set of custom exceptions like `throw new MyLibraryCantDoThisBecauseOfThatException().` ...You get my meaning.

If you add all necessary checks to ensure you can produce an output then don't wrap anything else.

```
public SomeObject SomeProcess(AnotherObject anotherObject){
    if(anotherObject==null) throw ArgumentNullException();
    if(anotherObject.MustBePositive<=0) throw ArgumentException("x must be positive");
    if(_someDepenedencyMyLibaryCreates.NotThere) throw new MyLibraryMissingDepencyException()

    NowIHaveEnoughInfoToDoMyJobWithNoTry(); 
}
```

Following these guidelines down the path your library should check for and throw all exceptions that would prevent it from completing its task within your locust of control. If you run into memory issues etc. then I would let those fall back naturally out of your library because you lived up to your bargain. The user should get enough information from your exception that it can easily be tracked down without a special decoder ring.

This leaves only bugs in your code such as index out of range. I would let them flow out naturally because wrapping everything and throwing a `SomethingBadHappened` exception will make fixing your code much harder.

Now there are caveats to this...such as database exceptions or exceptions in business type code that would reveal sensitive internals of your system. In these situations you might be forced to wrap and or check for a specific business class exception or database exception, logging the original, and returning a `SomthingBadHappened` exception with a guid or some reference to the exception you logged.

Another edge case is with web service libraries which may rely on a specific http response code. For that I would look into **Exception Shielding**.

Comment: I think this is a very good answer. I agree with you, usually validating all the input data and throwing the appropriate exceptions is the way to go (and as you say the rest of the exceptions do not need additional info since they are either system problems or errors in my code). I also considered this in my design. Anyway, I updated my question to explain why I would like to avoid explicit validation of input data if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts:

1. If your library adds additional information to exceptions, then yours will be the only library which does so. All of your users will have to learn how to get that extra information.
2. The fact that most libraries don't do anything like this should be a hint to you - either it wasn't necessary, or it wasn't useful, or they would have done it already. .NET has been in existence for 12 years now. You need to ask yourself why this particular wheel hasn't already been invented.
3. Before you do *anything* special with exceptions, make certain that your special features will actually be used. The special features should actually be a *requirement* of your library, complete with acceptance criteria and acceptance tests.

The fact is, there's very little need to catch specific exceptions, in practice, or to provide additional information in the exception. This is especially true in the case where the additional information will only be used for logging.

P.S. For some interesting ideas on logging, see the [Semantic Logging Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440729%28v=pandp.60%29.aspx). Even if you wind up not using, it the ideas are interesting.

Comment: Is it ok to have a uniform and predictable strategy for handling exceptions?  I agree with the part about not adding new information, but most large applications I have worked on have a policy on logging and exception handling so that things do not become unmanageable.

Comment: In most cases, the uniform and predictable strategy should be "don't handle exceptions". You then check to find out when that would cause your application to fail to meet its requirements. You then start to add just enough exception handling to meet the requirements, as late as possible. You will find there is much less need for exception handling than you might have assumed.

Comment: There is a reason Exception.Data is supported, there're definitely cases like that of the questioners that require this type of support.

Comment: Again, I would start from a specific requirement. It may be as simple as to add information to Exception.Data and ensure that the logging framework in use logs all values in Exception.Data.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I agree that sometimes additional information in exception may be of little help. But the fact that most libraries do not add extra information can be also caused by the reasons explained in the questions: it is not easy do do it in such a way that it will be visible to the users, so in most cases the extra effort (or hacks) may not worth it. I also updated my question to explain why additional information may be very useful in my case.

Comment: @JohnSaunders 'The fact is, there's very little need to catch specific exceptions, in practice, or to provide additional information in the exception. This is especially true in the case where the additional information will only be used for logging.' It is not clear what you mean with this. I think that it is useful to add additional information in the exceptions which will just be included in the logs (and not used for exception handling).

Comment: @bosonix: I meant that if the extra information will only be used in logging, that it might be better to explicitly log the extra information rather than attach the extra information to the exception and to then log the exception.

Comment: @JohnSaunders so, you mean that I should add logging facilities to my library instead of letting this task for the users of my library? Is this as common practice in .NET?

Comment: Yes, that's what you should do. You should not assume that your users will do _anything_ other than call your library. Of course, you should also allow for different levels of logging, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
namespace YourLibrary
{
   class Example
   {
       static void Main()
       {
            int [] v = null;
            try
            {
                v[1] = 10;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
               throw new MyException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyException : Exception
    {        
       public MyException(Exception e):base(e.GetType().ToString() + e.Message)
       {            
       }
    }
}
```

By doing that you are including the information from the previous exception inside your new one... You can insert e.GetType().ToString() somewhere inside e.Message too if you want... but since the property Message is readonly you need to pass the code for the formatting you wish inside this **base** call

## edit

I'm new to both c# and exceptions so... When I saw your question I started trying some things here and it seems like the console message you get when the exception is thrown is what is inside the **Message** property... and this property is set when you pass a string in the constructor and can't be changed since its read-only so I think this would solve your problem